# webkitSpeechRecognition in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, node-webkit

I am trying to figure out the best and most efficient way to take a voice input for a Google Chrome Extension I am developing,
I have been testing out webkitSpeechRecognition in JS in a webpage, trying to figure how to transfer to an Extension!